# How do I fix a "module not found" error?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules, bluetooth

I want to get a bluetooth-usb-stick running.

In the terminal, I enter `sudo modprobe btusb`,
but the output is: `FATAL: Module btusb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-25-generic`.
I am on a machine running ubuntu 20.04.

What might be the reasons for this module to be missing, and how can I add this module?

Comment: Try `apt-cache search btusb` to see the package to install.

Comment: @waltinator `apt-cache search btusb` returned an empty output.

Comment: Then, `apt-cache search bluetooth`, and `dpkg -S btusb`, and `locate btusb`.

Comment: @waltinator dpkg and locate indeed find a many files. One of them is /usr/lib/modules/5.11.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko

but modprobe doesn't seem to find that one?!

Comment: Do a file search on  https://packages.ubuntu.com => https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=btusb.ko&mode=exactfilename&suite=hirsute-updates&arch=any

Comment: @A.B strange, I found this filelist https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute-updates/amd64/linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-25-generic/filelist , however, comparing it to my own files in the very same folder, I am missing some of these files... what do you think - good idea to manually replace them with the ones from the link?

Comment: why not reinstall the package?

Comment: @A.B oops, I think this is the first time I used the `--reinstall` flag.. well that did the trick! Now `sudo modprobe btusb` doesn't complain about missing files anymore. As to what removed these files in the first place though I have no idea.. Well, thanks alot @A.B , @waltinator :)

Comment: Well, just in case anyone is interested: I now know what removed the btusb.ko (and potentially other files).. it was the install-script from the driver of a device I wanted to install: 
https://www.xmpow.com/products/mpow-bh519a-bluetooth-5-1-usb-adapter-for-pc
so if you got this device as well be careful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of commenters I was able to fix this issue by reinstalling ( `sudo apt install --reinstall <pkg>`. I found the related package on [ubuntu package-search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=btusb.ko&mode=exactfilename&suite=hirsute-updates&arch=any).

After this I found that what removed the btusb was the install-script (the Makefile, to be precise) from the download-files provided by the manufacturer. The related lines that made this happen are:

```
mv $(DRV_DIR)/btusb.ko $(DRV_DIR)/btusb_bak
cp -f $(SRC_DIR)/rtk_btusb.ko $(DRV_DIR)/rtk_btusb.ko
```

So it basically replaces btusb with rtk_btusb. Note to self: read the scripts, don't blindly execute...