# btusb.ko file missing...Getting "Module not found error"

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules, bluetooth

I have the issue of not being able to use my USB Bluetooth adapter(It is a CSR 4.0) on my Ubuntu OS 20.04.4 LTS with GNOME version 3.36.8... Normally this USB stick works perfectly on my Windows but over here it doesnt... So I went online and did almost everything possible.. Note I have tried the following commands

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
systemctl restart Bluetooth
systemctl restart Bluetooth logs
sudo rfkill unblock Bluetooth
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
sudo vim /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
sudo apt install bluez
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
sudo apt install bluez*
```

All of these I have tried until I came across a post which mentioned me not having the required driver installed for the USB Bluetooth Adapter... So I downloaded the driver specified but since the driver wasnt specifically for my adapter, trying to install it failed but ever since, I have had the issue of my Bluetooth toggle button not switching on even when my Bluetooth adapter is connected... I keep getting a " No Bluetooth Found Please Insert Dongle" message...

For better understanding on my issue.. I found this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/664143/how-do-i-fix-a-module-not-found-error?newreg=46dd089995114f49ad74ce643b1402c7)  which helps explain my current issue... Apparently the **btusb.ko** file is missing because the driver I was trying to install earlier manipulated it...

So from the post I mentioned earlier one of the comment suggested I run the command
`dpkg -S btusb`, and `locate btusb`

This is the result of my own output:
[image: Terminal Output]

Fortunately I located the missing package from the output which is highlighted

**Now the question is what next**

**Please Help**

Comment: The answer you found explains what to do: you need to reinstall the `linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-41-generic` package.

Comment: @StephenKitt Please how do I do that.... because the package list referenced in that post is not updated and it does not show how I can download them

Comment: First command in the post: `sudo apt install --reinstall <pkg>`, *i.e.* in your case `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-41-generic`.

Comment: @StephenKitt oo wow... this is great, it worked...my bluetooth option is no longer greyed out... but now I am back to the original issue and that  is "not seeing any devices" and once I leave that section, for instance if I toggle bluetooth on and I go to wifi settings and I go back to Bluetooth, I find out that the toggle is off... Please help